# Custom Log4j2 appender not working with storm

Tags: logging, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper, log4j2

We have created below logger configuration  in worker.xml of storm cluster

```
       <!-- This is new appender we want to add -->
    <FDPRollingFile name="RollingFileInfo" filename="${sys:storm.log.dir}/userlogs/info-${sys:logfile.name}"
        filepattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/userlogs/info-${sys:logfile.name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}" append="true">
            <PatternLayout>
             <pattern>${patternFdpNew}</pattern>
           </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
            </Policies> 
        </FDPRollingFile>
    <FDPRollingFile name="RollingFileDebug" filename="${sys:storm.log.dir}/userlogs/debug-${sys:logfile.name}"
            filepattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/userlogs/debug-${sys:logfile.name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}" append="true">
          <PatternLayout>
             <pattern>${patternFdpNew}</pattern>
           </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
            </Policies> 
    </FDPRollingFile>
    <FDPRollingFile name="RollingFileError" filename="${sys:storm.log.dir}/userlogs/error-${sys:logfile.name}"
            filepattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/userlogs/error-${sys:logfile.name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}" append="true">
        <PatternLayout>
             <pattern>${patternFdpNew}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
    </FDPRollingFile>
<!-- This is new appender we want to add -->
```

and custom logger defined in below fashion

```
    <Logger name="custom-logger" additivity="false" level="INFO">
     <appender-ref ref="RollingFileDebug" level="TRACE"/>
     <appender-ref ref="RollingFileError" level="WARN"/>
     <appender-ref ref="RollingFileInfo" level="INFO"/>
   </Logger>
```

In storm topology builder main class

```
   config.put("topology.classpath","/usr/local/Cellar/storm/mylogger.jar");
```

and In spout

```
     private static org.slf4j.Logger _logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("custom-    logger");
```

Now what happens it detect my jar  and write one line of log in  log file but post that doesn't log any line to th log file.

Comment: There is only one spout in topology for now  and configured with 2 executors.

Comment: Also default logger if we don't use custom logger is able to   log every log line to file as usual

Answer (score 0):

1. The name attribute of the logger element should be your package name, are you sure "custom-logger" is correct?
2. If you are using slf4j in your code, you must add log4j2 slf4j binding to your classpath, see [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for  reply. custom-logger is just a name  given to logger we are trying to use our own custom log appender  in storm . So custom-logger  is reffering to our appenders. Will check on log4j2 slf4j  binding.